# Rspec error - NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm now making Rspec for controller `SearchController`. This controller do search record by sql with parameter which was got by "get" request. The controller is as follow.

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:category] == 'All'
      @search_result = Item.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%# {params[:name]}%'")
    else
      @search_result = Item.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%#{params[:name]}%' AND category = '#{params[:category]}'")
    end
    if @search_result.empty? then
      redirect_to main_app.root_path, notice: "No items found matching your search criteria ! Modify your search."
    else
      @search_result=@search_result.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 3)
    end
  end
 end
```

Then I wrote simple Rspec test as follow. This test intends that at first the object `item` is made to use in controller. Also the stub (`Item.stub(:find_by_sql).and_return(item)`) is declared. Then do `get :index` with parameter `:category => 'All'`. My expect is that in the controller `if params[:category] == 'All'` is passed and `@search_result` is filled by object. (As I mentioned, the stub was already declared. Also object was already made. Then `Item.find_by_sql(*****)` would return object which was already declared.)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SearchController do

  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  describe "" do
     it "" do
      item = Item.new(auction_id:'1',min_bid_price:'100.0')
      item.save
      Item.stub(:find_by_sql).and_return(item)

      get :index, {:category => 'All'}, valid_session

      @search_result.should_not be_empty

     end
  end
end
```

Then I ran Rspec and unfortunately got the error as follow. I think `@search_result` could not be successfully filled with object, so "empty?" could not be called. However I have no idea about how to fix this. I already use many hours about this. I would like to have someone's help.

```
Failures:

  1) SearchController
     Failure/Error: get :index, {:category => 'All'}, valid_session
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method `empty?' for #<Item:0x523c980>
     # ./app/controllers/search_controller.rb:9:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/search_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

     Finished in 0.25 seconds
     1 example, 1 failure

  Failed examples:

     rspec ./spec/controllers/search_controller_spec.rb:8 # SearchController

     Randomized with seed 50151
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Item.stub(:find_by_sql).and_return(item)
```

You are stubbing find_by_sql and returning a single item instead of a collection of items.  The simple fix is to wrap it in an array:

```
Item.stub(:find_by_sql).and_return [item]
```

Note that this will only work if Array is modified to support `paginate` (will_paginate will do this if you require the `will_paginate/array' library).

Aside from this, as @PeterAlfvin has mentioned, you have a mistake near the end of your spec:

```
@search_result.should_not be_empty
```

Should actually be written as:

```
assigns(:search_result).should_not be_empty
```

This is because you can't access instance variables assigned by your controller action directly.

Answer (score 1):

While the error is occurring in your model, you also have a problem in your example.

You seem to be assuming that because `@search_result` is defined in the controller, it is directly accessible in your RSpec example. That is not the case.  `@search_result` is `nil` in the example because you have not assigned a value to it.

You *can*, however, access the `@search_result` instance variable in the controller through the RSpec `assigns` method, as in `assigns[:search_result]`.

Comment: In the example given, it's not nil - it's an Item.

Comment: The specific error message was: `undefined method 'empty?' for #<Item:0x523c980>`.  The problem is because of the stubbing performed, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but how is `@search_result` being defined? Are all instance variables of a controller `subject` accessible in an RSpec example?

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. The error is coming from the model, not the example.

Comment: It's not, and you're right on that point. I'll give you a +1 for that - although it's not the reason for the error observed here.

Comment: You threw me with your first comment in this thread, though. You said "In the _example_ given". Had you said, "in the index code" or at least "in the model", I might have picked up on it earlier. :-)